# Redirect old URLs from example.com/foo to example.com/foo.php using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have revamped a website and now the URLs are different in their format.

Formerly a page was `www.example.com/about`.

Now it is `www.example.com/about.php`

How can I write a redirect rule so that when a user clicks an old URL (from search engines or whathaveyou) 'www.example.com/about' it receives a 301 redirection over to `www.example.com/about.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Updated Answer:
Sorry, this was not as straightofeward as I thought.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule (.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)$ $1.php
```

It should be in the root web directory where your URL maps to, sounds like public_html.

Comment: I got a 500 Server Internal error on using this code as the contents for .htaccess in the public_html directory.. Should the file be in the root directory instead?

Comment: I'll give the answer to you since you're the only one that tried to help me; thanks anyway. I got the solution from my webhost.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using .htaccess was a horrible reality and I found that my host (HostGator) has a 'redirect menu' in the Control panel and I manually did the redirects there.